# How can I get a QFileDialog to prompt for overwrite?

Tags: qt, qt4, qfiledialog

I have a QDialog that opens a QFileDialog like so:

```cpp
QFileDialog fd(this);
fd.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);

if (fd.exec()) {
    // save data to a file
}
```

Unfortunately, [the default behavior](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) doesn't seem to be quite so default, and the file dialog doesn't prompt me about overwriting if I select a file that already exists.  Calling [`setConfirmOverwrite(true)`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#confirmOverwrite-prop) or [`setOption(QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite, false)`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#setOption) first doesn't help either.  I've tested this both on Qt 4.7.3 and 4.7.4 on both Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows XP.

I looked around and found [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11539).  [`QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) had this issue, but it was specific to Maemo and fixed well before Qt 4.7.3 came out.  If I use that method in my application it works just fine, I get prompted about overwriting the file.  (I don't want to use `getSaveFileName()` for unrelated reasons.)

I can't find anyone else complaining about this not working for them.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?  I think it might be due to the dialog not knowing whether it's just a simple Open dialog where prompting wouldn't make sense, but I don't see a way to tell it it's a Save dialog (beyond setting the confirm-overwrite option, which fails), and the documentation *does* say it should prompt by default.

Comment: I have the same issue with Qt 4.8.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also be sure that the dialog is in save mode, as it will not think you are overwriting a file when in open mode. You can do this by calling `fd.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);` in your code example. See [QFileDialog::acceptMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#acceptMode-prop).

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!  Don't know how I missed it.  I hope your register your SO account and stick around :)