# Overwrite an existing file using Qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to overwrite an existing file using Qt. Since `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` will always replace the selected file if it already exists, I've tried creating a custom QFileDialog in over to get to my goal so I used what has been suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285575/how-can-i-get-a-qfiledialog-to-prompt-for-overwrite) but it seems not to work...

What I've tried so far:

```
    QFileDialog diag(this);
    diag.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
    diag.setNameFilter(tr("Test (*.tst)"));
    diag.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
    diag.exec();
    QStringList namefile = diag.selectedFiles();
    QFile file(namefile[0]);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << ui->lineEdit->text() << endl;
    }
    file.close();
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Take a look to `QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite` option. It may help.

Comment: @vahancho This worked pretty fine Thank you